# Qual programa faz o Delphi 2010 sublinhar em vermelho códigos errados?

Tags: delphi

Notei que o Delphi RAD XE sublinha em vermelho códigos incorretos e também já vi o Dephi 7 fazer o mesmo, esta uma imagem descreve bem o que quero dizer. [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everton, esta funcionalidade foi introduzida a partir do Delphi 2007, se não me engano. Nunca vi ela no Delphi 7, mas o nome da funcionalidade é Syntax Checker.
Existem plugins que podem te ajudar como o CnPack ou Delphi Experts.

### Atualização em 13/08/2018

Conforme nosso colega @aguena mencionou, esta funcionalidade já existe no Delphi 2006. Nas opções de Code Insight você pode habilitar e desabilitar o Error Insight, que é o plugin responsável por grifar as linhas as quais a IDE julga estar com erros. Porém na maior parte dos casos ela grifa linhas que estão saudáveis, eu particularmente as ignorava (não desligava).

Acredito que pelo motivo de o Delphi ser uma linguagem compilada, muitas vezes a IDE aguardava uma compilação (mesmo que em background) para validar os erros ou não. Então as linhas ficavam sempre grifadas. Até nos dias de hoje este comportamento ocorre, mas com menos frequência.

Answer (score 1):

A minha versão de Delphi é a 2006 (Turbo Explorer) e ela já oferece o *Code Insight* na IDE.

Dentre os recursos do *Code Insight*, o *Error Insight* é o que sublinha em vermelho os locais de erros de sintaxe. Mas esse recurso tem muitos bugs (até nas versões mais recentes do Delphi) e às vezes indica erros que não existem.

Caso essas indicações tornem-se incômodas, basta desligar o *Error Insight*.

Na minha versão, o caminho para desligar essa opção é: *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Editor Options* -> *Code Insight*. Chegando nessa janela, basta desmarcar a opção *Error Insight*.